# Проблемы с обработкой нажатия клавиши "Enter" в консольном меню, управление которым осуществляется с помощью клавиш ВВЕРХ-ВНИЗ

Tags: c++

Есть меню в консоли. Управляется клавишами ВВЕРХ-ВНИЗ. Когда я выбираю первый пункт меню, то после выведения результата не получаться выбрать второй пункт(автоматически выполняется первый). Как это исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Menu[2] = {"Enter number", "Exit"};
    int pointer = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        system("cls");
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
        cout << "Main Menu\n\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        {
            if (i == pointer)
            {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 11);
                cout << Menu[i] << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 15);
                cout << Menu[i] << endl;
            }
        }

        while(true)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) != 0)
            {
                pointer -= 1;
                if (pointer == -1)
                {
                    pointer = 1;
                }
                break;
            }
            else
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) != 0)
            {
                pointer += 1;
                if (pointer == 2)
                {
                    pointer = 0;
                }
                break;
            }
            else
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) != 0)
            {
                switch (pointer)
                {
                    case 0:
                    {
                        int number;
                        cout << "\nEnter number --> ";
                        cin >> number;
                        cout << "\nThe number is ";
                        cout << number;
                        Sleep(1000);
                    } break;
                    case 1:
                    {
                        return 0;
                    } break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        Sleep(150);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если вы пользуетесь WinAPI для управления консолью, использовать `cin` для ввода может оказаться не лучшей идеей. Они не дружат между собой.

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы уже выбрали пункт Enter number, вы вводите число и нажимаете Enter, смысл в том, что при отпускании клавиши, GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) не равен нулю и поэтому условие снова срабатывает.
Для решения данной проблемы необходима очистка буфера клавиатуры.
Решение есть по ссылке:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222277/delete-key-press-historygetkeystate-c

Функция ClearConsoleInputBuffer(), её следует поместить перед while(true).